# Editing the URL with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a website where the link is simply set with an ID and I've now added a title to that too but I want the url to look better in the browser and I've heard that this can be done using htaccess.

Here is the url as it stands and how I want it to look:

```
http://mysite.co.uk/article.php?title=The-Title-Goes-Here&id=1391613085-558678562
to
http://mysite.co.uk/The-Title-goes-Here/1391613085-558678562
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: With a URL rewrite, what have you tried? Questions which show no effort are off-topic. Go and read about `.htaccess` files and Apache mod-rewrite then come back when you run into a specific problem with your rewrite rules.

Comment: Trust me, I've read about it but I just don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.+)/(\d+)-(\d+)   article.php?title=$1&id=$2-$3
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not working. In fact it seems to be preventing the images from loading?

Comment: For images you need one more htaccess file inside images folder which    
`rewriteengine off`

Comment: Also please make sure that you have rewrite module loaded in apache

Comment: Sounds like this is going to be even more complicated than I thought - May have to leave it as it is because it's more than likely that my host won't allow me to edit apache on their server